# Hibernate Entity Class: One columns with XML content

Tags: xml, hibernate, orm, hibernate-mapping

I have a table with one column containing XML, the question is that how do I map that column to hibernate entity class variable. I can do this using string, but I want to get a Document object.

Regards,

Answer (score 0):

You can use Hibernate [custom user types](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/manual/en-US/html/ch06.html#types-custom) or [JPA Converters](http://www.thoughts-on-java.org/jpa-21-how-to-implement-type-converter/) for this purpose.